# How to fix 'rails aborted' error when running "rails db:create db:migrate "?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error message I get:

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_record/railties/databases.rake
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `rescue in load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:52:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:49:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:246:in `instance_exec'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:246:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:255:in `each'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:255:in `each_registered_block'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:246:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Prodigy/code/PierceF/conqueredtime/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/Prodigy/code/PierceF/conqueredtime/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Prodigy/code/PierceF/conqueredtime/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/Users/Prodigy/code/PierceF/conqueredtime/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: 

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also tried `bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate` but that still had no effect.

Comment: Are you sure rails is installed properly?

Comment: @dbugger I think so, I did not have this issue with another rails project..

Comment: try `bundle exec spring stop` and then run all your commands

Comment: @adityapandit17 I ran that and it said ```Spring is not running``` but I still got the same error after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was having this error only with this rails project and not the others, I thought maybe I'll try starting a brand new rails project and copy-paste the code/files from the older project into this new one. That fixed the issue! I guess since this is a small app I was able to get away with it.